# I have lost my residential permit while travelling in India - what should I do?

Tags: visas, india, paperwork, permits

I am staying in India for 6 months, so have had to register with the Foreigners Registration Office in Bangalore. I was given a residential permit which I have misplaced, and am expected to surrender on exit from the country. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have a copy of it? (A quick google indicates the procedures differ quite a bit depending on if you have a copy)

Comment: No, I do not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried phoning the FRRO (different from the FRO) to ask them? Google suggests you may be able to get the FRRO to issue you with an exit visa despite the missing residence permit. Experiences with the FRO seem more hit and miss, but you could always drop in and ask them if you have the time to spare...